# How to start already-provisioned Vagrant box without losing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, vagrant

I get this error whenever I try to start my vagrant box with `vagrant up` (on Mac OSX) without the `--provision` flag:

```
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I'm able to `ssh` into the vagrant box, but I can't access the web server.

The box starts and I can access the server when I run `vagrant up --provision`, but that deletes all the data from each session.

The problem occurs after entering `vagrant halt` and trying to start the box again with `vagrant up`. It doesn't happen when entering `vagrant up` after `vagrant destroy`, but `destroy` also gets rid of all the databases, etc. so I want another option. Does anyone have suggestions?

I'm using an existing repo with its own `Vagrantfile`. The project uses Ruby on Rails and Sqlite3.

Edit: [link to vagrantfile](https://github.com/yamilethmedina/kimball/blob/development/Vagrantfile)

Comment: Could you share your vagrant file?

Comment: @axlj this should be public: https://github.com/yamilethmedina/kimball/blob/development/Vagrantfile

Comment: Can you post all of the output from `vagrant up`?  I think this is just a notice.  The vagrantfile has a provisioner setup and this vm has already been provisioned.

Comment: I don't like starting services from a provisioner for this very reason.  The provisioner should create a service that starts on boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your provisioning launches rails command but after its not persisting so when you restart the VM this command does not run and rails does not launch, You could for example add the command in a cron job to make sure it starts automatically.

But to keep things simple, you can add the following provisioner to start rails every time you boot the VM

```
  config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, run: "always", inline: %(
    cd /vagrant/
    bundle exec unicorn_rails -D
    sudo service nginx restart
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding this to `Vagrantfile` (immediately before `end`) worked. It booted with `vagrant up` and kept my existing user database intact.

Comment: In my case, I had to do a system/machine restart as well.

Answer (score 1):

Running `vagrant destroy`, and then restart by `running vagrant` up solved my issue.